# What is the latest version Hibernate for Java 1.5

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, compatibility

We are using Weblogic 10, so maximum Java allowed there is Java 1.5
I inherited the code using EJB3
So, I will have to work on it within a realm of my Java 1.5 limitation.
I think, original designers had in mind to use Hibernate for implementing Data access, and 
at some point we will migrate to JBOSS, so would like to keep Hibernate as a choice
There is one sitting in a project - version 3.2.1.ga.  Same is a version for hibernate-entitymanager.jar

What is the latest version of Hibernate that I can use for this?  I understand there were some changes in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hibernate 3.x workes with JDK 4 and 5, 
The 4.x requires 6. 
I think you should go with HIbernate 3.6.x. The last version in 3.x was 3.6.10.

You will not find it on hibernate site you will to goto sourcefoge.net to get this version.
 [here's](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/3.6.10.Final/) the link

Comment: Thanks.  This running around with versions really burdensome..
I read some articles that suggest me do something related to the task at hand, and then it comes out to be not working because my Hibernate version doesn't support it, etc..