# Which JDK version should be used for hibernate 3.6.1

Tags: java, hibernate

i want to know whether jdk1.5 supports hibernate3.6.1.

Comment: Could you also post the code that's causing the issue?

Comment: `JspApplicationContext` has nothing to do with hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this [What is the latest version Hibernate for Java 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806926/what-is-the-latest-version-hibernate-for-java-1-5)

This tells JDK 1.5 supports hibernate 3.x i.e. it supports 3.6.1.